# « offusquant » est-il synonyme d'« offensif » ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, définition

J'avais l'impression que le mot « offusquant » pouvait être employé en tant qu'adjectif, pour signifier « offensif ».

Mais en ce moment je n'en suis pas sûr.

Certes, il y a des exemples de cet usage adjectival sur le site web Reverso, mais je ne sais pas si celui-ci est fiable.

Si vous pouvez faire la lumière là-dessus, je serai reconnaissant.

Merci!

Comment: "Offusquant" n'est pas très utilisé, et ne me semble pas être un synonyme pour "offensif". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=offusquant%2C+offensif&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, mais pas pour des raisons de synonymie. C'est plutôt que *offensif* ne s'utilise tout simplement pas dans un sens lié au concept d'insulte ou d'outrage, mais unique au sens lié à l'agression, c'est un pur anglicisme de l'utiliser pour traduire l'anglais *offensive*. L'adjectif français correct est *offensant*.

Les verbes équivalents à ces adjectifs, *offenser* et *offusquer*, ont des signification très proches l'une de l'autre. Toutefois, le terme "offusquant" sous forme adjectivale n'est pas particulièrement commun (en tout cas pas assez pour être dans mon *Robert* de 2007), mais on le retrouve un peu partout, par exemple chez Baudelaire.

Je privilégierais personnellement *offensant*, mais *offusquant* en est clairement un synonyme dont l'usage n'est pas fondamentalement inapproprié.